# Umbraco - reference a published image

Tags: razor, umbraco

I'm trying to ref a published image in Umbraco but 'MediaById' seems to be incorrect, what is the correct way to reference this?

```
<img src="@Model.MediaById("focusImage") alt="@Model.GetPropertyValue("focusAltText")/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
@{
   var mediaId = Model.GetPropertyValue<int>("focusImage");
   var media = Umbraco.TypedMedia(mediaId);
}

<img src="@media.Url" alt="@Model.GetPropertyValue("focusAltText")/>
```